# How to send complex data to controller?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to send an object look like

```
{
  jobno :8001,
  formid :FF000123,
  type:02,
  fd03:["1,"2","3"]
}
```

how to map this data with a controller in asp.net core?

Comment: `fetch(apiUrl, {method: 'post', body: JSON.stringify({ jobno :8001, formid :FF000123, type:02, fd03:["1,"2","3"] }) })`

Comment: hei man , how can i map this ? do i need to create a class that look like this in backend ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in Visual Studio **"Paste JSON as Classes"** feature, it will create a C# class (or multiple classes) to match the JSON that you pasted.

For more info see here:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/
- https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2018/02/paste-json-and-xml-as-class.aspx

Note that your JSON (example) is **incorrectly formatted**, this is what you'd have to "Paste Special" for it to work:

```
{ "jobno": 8001, "formid": "FF000123", "type": 02, "fd03": ["1","2","3"] }
```

If you are not using Visual Studio, then you can generate C# classes here:
https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple - use c# class to describe this data.
Something like that:

```
public sealed class Request
{
    [JsonProperty("jobno")]
    public int JobNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("formid")]
    public string FormId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fd03")]
    public string[] Fd03 { get; set; }
}
```

Then add your class as argument to your controller method.